# Emacs first line when opening a file always off

Tags: emacs

I'm using Unix, and say I have a file 'test.txt' that contains this

```
test1
test2
test3
```

if I open it in emacs by typing at the prompt: emacs test.txt, I always get this

```
                                                        t
est1
test2
test3
```

with the first t always flush on the right margin.  Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure that the file contains what you think it does? Maybe try `less test.txt` to make sure. Does this happen when running `emacs -Q test.txt`? The `-Q` flag prevents Emacs from loading any configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen also when you start Emacs without using your init file, i.e. from `emacs -Q`?
I'm guessing not.

In that case, narrow down your init file to find the culprit code. Do this by recursively bisecting it: Comment out 1/2 of the code to find the culprit half. Then comment out 3/4 of it, then 7/8, etc.

You will quickly find out what the problem is. You can use `M-x comment-region` to comment a region of text, and use the same command with `C-u` to uncomment a region.